# C How to turn strings passed by command into array

Tags: c, arrays, string, command, malloc

I'm trying to turn strings into arrays. However, when I try to print the values to test it, it won't print anything.

**Command**

> a.c BTC IOT NEO ETH XRP

**Expected Output**

> BTC.csv
>    IOT.csv

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char m[9];
}moeda;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *csv;
    int n = argc-1;
    moeda *m;

    m = (moeda*)malloc(n*sizeof(moeda));


    for(int z=1; z<=n; z++)
        {
            int i = 0;
            sprintf(m[i].m, "%s.csv", argv[z]);

            i++;
        }

    printf("%s\n", m[0].m);
    printf("%s\n", m[1].m);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try declaring `i=0;` outside for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `i` *inside* the loop, meaning it gets set to 0 for each iteration. Try

```
int i = 0;
for(int z=1; z<=n; z++)
    {
        sprintf(m[i].m, "%s.csv", argv[z]);

        i++;
    }
```

Or just

```
for(int z=1; z<=n; z++)
    {
        sprintf(m[z - 1].m, "%s.csv", argv[z]);
    }
```